# Vaadin 14 re-routing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm working on a Vaadin 14 application.  I want users to be able to go to a certain URL and, depending on certain conditions, get rerouted to one of several views which have their own route.

I know how re-routing works using `BeforeEnterHandler` / `BeforeEnterObserver`.  But this works only to interrupt navigation to a known route, which as far as I can see needs to be linked to a class implementing `Component` either by using `@Route` as an annotation for that class or dynamically registered.  Does this mean I need to create a dummy `Component` implementation with this route, which will never be shown, just to be able to reroute in a `BeforeEnterHandler`?  Or is there some cleaner way to hook into the routing lifecycle and reroute even before the corresponding view component is looked up?

*Update:*
*I wrote this question with re-routing in mind, but I found out I will use forwarding instead since `forwardTo` updates the browser URL as well, and that is what I want.  But the question remains the same otherwise, since I still need a route to be able to forward to another one.*

*Update 2:*
*Since I need to supply query parameters to the target views, I can't even use `forwardTo`.  `UI.navigate` apparently doesn't work correctly when called during navigation, so I needed to handle an `AfterNavigationEvent` and call `UI.navigate` there.  This means navigation is already done at this point so my route definitely needs a `Component` as a navigation target.  Both these issues (no route handling possible without creating a dummy UI component and `forwardTo` not accepting query parameters) seem like basic shortcomings of the Vaadin framework's routing support.*

Comment: If the conditions logic cannot be done while leaving the previous view (-> if your dummy view is the entry point of the user into the app), then the dummy view with rerouting logic sounds like the way to go. I am not aware of any direct Router meddling to achieve what you want, so my answer would be to continue with what you planned. But I could very well be wrong, so I won't write it as an actual answer. There could indeed be a way to avoid a dummy view. In Java, you can access the Router with `UI.getCurrent().getRouter()`, but I can't find a way to add a Route without using a `Component`.

Comment: @kscherrer Indeed this route should be an app entry point.  In fact, personally I think any view should be bookmarkable and thus accessible directly as if it were an entry point.

Comment: I worded that poorly. You giving the URL to the user is the very definition of an app entry point. Which is why you cannot do your custom conditions logic using a `BeforeLeaveObserver` in the previous view (because there is no previous view). 
You won't get around creating a dummy component.

Comment: @kscherrer OK.  It seems even a dummy component won't allow me to do what I want since my target URL has query parameters, and there is no `forwardTo` method on `BeforeEnterEvent` that accepts query parameters :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using a *route* is the cleanest way to do it and it's aligned with the concepts in the framework—anything (in Vaadin) that "listens" to a URL is a route. You can define routes with `@Route` or you can register them dynamically with `RouteConfiguration` if that helps. Another option is to use a Servlet to redirect to the desired view, but I don't think that's cleaner.

Comment: Indeed defining a route is the cleanest, but there seems to be no way to define a route other than creating a view component.  `@Route` doesn't work on plain classes and `RouteConfiguration.setRoute(...)` requires a `Class<? extends Component>` parameter.  So it looks like a dummy component is necessary.

Comment: FYI I've created https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10419 and https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10420 for my two issues with Vaadin's routing support.  I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer just in case someone else from Vaadin comes up with an even better solution.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issues. If the answer was useful, can you mark it as accepted, please?

Comment: OK I guess the short answer is no clean way exists at this point, you have to create a dummy component in order to handle a route, or use a servlet/filter.